# Custom exceptions and throw c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
    public DataTable executeQuery(string querySql, List<MySqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (connectionLocal = getConnection())
            {
                connectionLocal.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(querySql, connectionLocal);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                foreach (MySqlParameter param in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(param);
                }

                MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                dataTable.TableName = "tabla";
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new DAOException("tst",e);
            //return null;
        }
    }
```

and...

```
public class DAOException : Exception
{
    public DAOException(String msg, Exception inner)
        : base(msg, inner)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un problema... Por favor contacta al administrador!"); return;
    }

}
```

But the following when the exception occurs, it appears:

http://s17.postimg.org/6quh6xs6n/daoex.png

I would like to know what is the right way to use try-catch to throw.

Thank you!!!

Comment: inspect `e.Message` and `e.InnerException`

Comment: @Shyju Where? In DAOException?

Answer (score 1):

The place to *handle* an exception is the `catch` block, not the exception class itself. So you can show your MessageBox in your catch block and terminate your application (e.g. via `Application.Exit()`).

An `Exception` class is nothing more than a data container that can take information about the error that occurred. By throwing that exception you say "I can't handle that situation, someone else (the caller) should take care of that!" And you use an `Exception` class to provide information about what happend and where.

The code that *can* (or wants to) handle this exception implements the `try....catch` blocks. It *catches* the exception and - for example - logs the information like `Message` and `StackTrace`.

If the exception is not caught by anyone, it will eventually crash the whole application and the operating system will take care by creating dumps etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the catch block you catch the Exception which was thrown earlier, then you throw a new DAOException, which you don't handle anywhere.

What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want to show an error message and stop program execution. How I could try this in the DAOException class?

Comment: Personally I think you don't really need your own Exception class, in the catch block you just need to show a MessageBox and exit your program. Of course you can also do it with an own Exception class, then you need to handle the thrown CustomException in order to be able to show your own MessageBox not the one of .NET. (After an unhandled Exception, the .NET shows an error message, which you can't control so you need to also handle your CustomException.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could handle the exception in the DAOException class to avoid unhandled Exception?

Comment: You shouldn't handle an Exception in itself because it doesn't make any sense. A custom Exception is needed when your code can cause a 'custom' error, for which there is no Exception in the .NET framweork, not when you want to handle one, which has been thworn by .NET (like exceptions in connection with MySql). In your case you just need to handle the thrown Exception in the catch block, for example by showing a MessageBox and closing your app. No custom exception is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just log the error message or show it to user you can modify your catch block by MessageBox invocation:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un problema... Por favor contacta al administrador!");
    return null; // or Application.Exit(); or other code you want
}
```

There is a [guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014(v=vs.110).aspx) about exception throwing designing and caching. Remember that your data in memory and current context can be corrupted after exception was thrown. Then you must handle this scenario or terminate the application.

There are [many](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx) materials about [exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229005(v=vs.100).aspx) and it is really more the one answer theme. For example, it's a good idea to show at least exception message to user or log exception details to the log-file for future debug.